# Launching Firefox leads to system freeze

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, freeze, acer-travelmate

I'm running Linux Mint 19 on an Acer Travelmate, so definitely not a high-end device. Since switching to LM19, I don't detect any problems whatsoever, except for this one:
Starting Firefox is impossible. The firefox windows does not even appear. All I notice is that RAM goes to 100% and that the system freezes completely. I might be able to move the mouse pointer though and it will respond with considerable delay. This behavior started less than a year ago with a new firefox version. Using an older version (I think 52) works without problems. Starting from the terminal also does not reveal anything. The only thing I can do is REISUB. I'm rather clueless at the moment what to do about it.

Comment: Are you familiar with `strace`?, it's a tracing like tool which helps to diagnosis.

Comment: I was not. Until now :) I started firefox with `strace -e trace=open,close,read,write -o ff.log firefox`. I can see the memory usage slowly rising until after some time 100% is reached and I hit Ctrl+C. The log file amounts to 10MB and consists to 99% of the following line: `read(48, "\30\0\214?~\37\23\37|\32\240\31\267\30\v\30<\23\362\22\"\22\372\21l\21\257\20\331\v\317\v"..., 16384) = 16384` Not quite sure what to do with this cryptic information.